# Bug identifying

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]
Can anyone help me identify this insect found in my office today?

Comment: If you could let us see the top-side of the bug, it would help us identify it.

Comment: It can help identification, if you add the approximate size and the geographical local of that bug.

Answer (score 1):

That is a stink bug, order Hemiptera, family Pentatomidae. My guess is that it is a brown marmorated stink bug *Halyomorpha halys*, not because I can identify it as such, but rather, because this species frequently invades homes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug

[image]